# Ideal Diode in two sources circuit

Tags: diodes, circuit-design

Can somebody explain me why is there this solution for V in the first problem [here](https://www.ece.uic.edu/~zyang/Teaching/20142015SpringECE340/Downloads/HW/HW03sol.pdf).

[image]

I understand when we have conducting or cut of but how is V calculated? I am very confused

Thank you for your time

Comment: What do you understand is the action of an ideal diode? Why don't you think any of these can't be answered?

Comment: I can't understand how is V calculated

Comment: As long as an ideal diode is forward biased, its resistance is zero.  As long as it is reverse biased, its resistance is infinite.  Once you replace each diode with an ideal wire or remove it from the circuit as appropriate, each circuit is easy to solve.  Note that these are simple cases and this simple rule cannot be used in all cases.

Comment: A diode only conducts in one direction.  The diode symbol looks a bit like an arrow head to show you which way it conducts.  For an ideal diode we assume that the voltage is the same at both ends of the diode when it is conducting.  For a real diode the anode will be slightly higher than the cathode.  We only need to consider the ideal case here.  Does this help?

Comment: thank u. i understand what you say. f.e in the first example we replace with a wire because it conducts. Why is V = -3V??? Why not 3-(-3) = 6V. that's what I cant understand

Comment: Because there's still the 10k resistor (actually doesn't matter what value it has) in between the two nodes. If you replace the conducting diode with a wire, your 'V' node is directly tied to the -3V so it has to be -3V as well.

Comment: ok understood. What's the role of the resistor there?

Comment: *Why is V = -3V* For case (a): we determined that the diode is in forward mode so conducting. That means it **connects/shorts** the -3 V at the bottom directly to point "V". So point "V" becomes -3 V. The resistor is actually only needed to make the diode go into forward mode.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of DC circuit analysis, think of an "ideal" diode as an automatic, SPST switch.  When the current is tying to move the same direction that the diode symbol points, the switch is closed and electrons flow.  When the current is trying to move in the opposite direction, the switch is open and there is no current.  Note that it is the polarity of the voltage across the diode that the diode actually responds to, but the shape of a diode symbol is a convenient way to visualize what is going on.